# Question about the templates

Tags: 7, theming

I create a module and implement hook_menu():

```
function mymodule_menu(){
  $items['mymodule/list']=array(/*...*/);
  return $items;
}
```

then I create a theme and create page.tpl.php and page--mymodule-list.tpl.php at the same directory.

now I can access http://localhost/?q=mymodule/list, but it use page.tpl.php to render the page, instead of page--mymodule-list.tpl.php.

How should I do to make it render the page with page--mymodule-list.tpl.php?

Comment: Have you cleared the caches since adding your template file? And do you have a copy of the core page.tpl.php in your theme as well?

Comment: @Clive Yes, I have cleared the caches. And I found if I rename page--mymodule-list.tpl.php to page--mymodule.tpl.php, it work fine.

Comment: this is may due to admin theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ['rules'](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) for the page.tpl.php template suggestions state you need to substitue each `/` in the page for **2** dashes, so your template file needs to be called:

> page--mymodule--list.tpl.php

Remember to the clear the cache again once you've made the change